# Check for secure connection via proxy using LWP::UserAgent and HTTP::Request

Tags: perl, https, proxy, user-agent, lwp

Years ago I write some Perl code using `LWP::UserAgent` and `HTTP::Request`.
That code runs fine, and one part of it is checking for a secured connection by inspecting the response header for `Client-SSL-Cipher`, `Client-SSL-Cert-Subject`, and `Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer` (besides a `https:` URL).

However when the program uses a proxy (via `$user_agent->env_proxy()`) the response does not include those `Client-SSL` headers.
(The `via` headers indicate that the proxy (`squid/2.7.STABLE5`) is used.)

The proxy environment lists the `https_proxy` using a `http://some_host:3128/` URL.

How can I get those SSL-details while using a proxy? The versions being used are those for SLES12 SP4, so neither very old nor very recent (perl 5.18.2).

### (Partial) Example Header without Proxy

```
   '_headers' => HTTP::Headers=HASH(0x55bfc8d76470)
      '::std_case' => HASH(0x55bfc90a0980)
         'client-date' => 'Client-Date'
         'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer'
         'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num'
         'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer'
         'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject'
         'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher'
         'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class'
         'strict-transport-security' => 'Strict-Transport-Security'
         'x-content-type-options' => 'X-Content-Type-Options'
         'x-frame-options' => 'X-Frame-Options'
      'accept-ranges' => 'bytes'
      'client-date' => 'Tue, 24 Mar 2020 10:45:23 GMT'
      'client-peer' => '134.76.12.6:443'
      'client-response-num' => 1
      'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '/C=DE/O=Verein zur Foerderung eines Deutschen Forschungsnetzes e. V./OU=DFN-PKI/CN=DFN-Verein Global Issuing CA'
      'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '/C=DE/ST=NIEDERSACHSEN/L=GOETTINGEN/O=Gesellschaft fuer wissenschaftliche Datenverarbeitung/CN=ftp6.gwdg.de'
      'client-ssl-cipher' => 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384'
      'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
      'connection' => 'close'
```